# React Webpack _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I developed a web application(almost 15-20 Pages) in Nodejs Using React.Here I am use Webpack bundler. Every thing working fine,But my issue detail:I was make one common file(bundle.js) of all pages react code.When I compile it and run it.It show me error message in console is._registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.I know it is react error because it can't find div having Id which is use inside bundle.js for another page on index.html(Home Page).So any body help me here for provide me guide about my problem.Which is the best way for deal with that situation.Make saprate bundle files for each pages or any another way solve this problem using same bundle file for each pages and solve this issue.If any method to solve this problem please provide it me here.
Thanks 
My Code is Here:
webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: { path: path.join(__dirname, './js/'), filename: 'bundle.js' },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /jquery[\\\/]src[\\\/]selector\.js$/, loader: 'amd-define-factory-patcher-loader' },
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
            { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' },
        ]
    }
};
```

main.js

```
import 'jquery/src/jquery/';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js';

/*****************  React Components Here  *****************/
import './src/browser/HomeComponent.js';//this is use for homepage component

import './src/browser/LoginComponent.js';//this is use for loginpage component
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
<div id="home" ></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How did you solve it? I am having same issue